# Is there a way to create a webfilter in springboot to add a message in the http header by checking a criteria in the payload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I am working on a Spring Boot services which have some search endpoints that return lists of objects.

These endpoints should have a limit on how many objects could be returned, currently this limit is 500.
The frontend devs requested me to add a message when this limit is reached.

I could accomplished this by checking the size of the list returned and add a warning header in the HttpServletResponse response as suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-header).

```java
    @GetMapping()
    public List<Potatoes> getPotatoes(RequestPotatoesParameters params, HttpServletResponse response) {

        List<Potato> potatoes = potatoService.getPotatoes(params);

        if (potatoes.size() >= 500) {
            response.addHeader("Warning", "Result is greater than 500 records limit. Please, refine your search.");
        }

        return potatoes;
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that I need to add this code on every method.
So, I tried to use a `@Webfilter` as suggested in the same page I mentioned but I was not able to retrieve the list and verify its size.

```java
@WebFilter("/potatoes")
public class AddResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    List<Potato> potatoes = ? //how can I get this from the Servlet response?

    if (potatoes.size() >= 500) {
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Warning", "Result is greater than 500 records limit. Please, refine your search.");
    }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Would anyone have an alternative solution or know how can I retrieve the list to check its size?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your filter as shown below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper;
import org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingResponseWrapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@Configuration
public class AddResponseHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter
{
    /**
     * Add URL of you API. Make sure your value should not allow all the requests.
     */
    public static final String VALID_API_URL = "/api/v1/potatoes";

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
        try
        {
        if(request.getRequestURI().contains(VALID_API_URL))
        {
            List<Potato> potatoes  = objectMapper.readValue(wrappedResponse.getContentAsByteArray(), new TypeReference<List<Potato>>() {});

            if(potatoes.size() > 500)
            {
                wrappedResponse.setHeader("Warning", "Result is greater than 500 records limit. Please, refine your search.");
            }
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
    }


    /**
     * You can also implement this method for custom filtering control
     */
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, pcsutar. I have tried it but it messes with the documentation generatade by swagger. It seems that the filter is chaning the response besides reading the list size.

Comment: Hi @RafaelJunqueira, The solution I have provided is processing all the requests. I showed you how to retrieve list from response. Could you please provide the error? I am editing my answer which will show you how to filter requests based on URL.

Comment: Hi pcsutar, the  List<Potato> potatoes is always empty. Not sure why but it is not able to parse the values to the list.

Comment: 2021-05-10 16:44:51.349 ERROR 31240 --- [nio-8084-exec-1] rFilter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$46422a52 : No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: (byte[])""; line: 1, column: 0]

Comment: Hi Rafael, I have checked the error message provided by you. It seems the filter is processing some unwanted requests. Could you please share your filter and rest controller? I am editing my answer to ignore the exception to get rid of this error message while processing unwanted requests.